# Boolean from response server not visible in table ant

Tags: react-native

I use `https://ant.design/components/table/` for react-native project.

I have fetch and all data works except boolead value!

Any suggestion?

```
  const columns = [
    {
      title: 'Test',
      dataIndex: 'testbool',
      key: 'testbool',
      width: '20%',
    }, ...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

after viewing your code you can try this:

```
const columns = [{
      title: 'Test',
      dataIndex: 'testbool',
      key: 'testbool',
      width: '20%',
      render : (text) => String(text),
    }, ...
```

this works in my code for accessing the boolean value. Hope it works in yours as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can also do something like this:

```
const columns: TableColumnsType<TableData> = [
    {
      title: "Payment Card",
      dataIndex: "hasActivePaymentCard", 
      key: "hasActivePaymentCard", 
      render: (value: boolean) => renderBoolean(value)
    },
  ]
```

```
const renderBoolean = (value: boolean) => {
    return (
      <Checkbox checked={value} ></Checkbox>
    );
  }
```